# Ручная реализация массивов

Tags: javascript

Представим, что массивов в Javascript нет; нужно написать класс MyArray (используя знания из предыдущих глав книги, прототипы пока не пройдены). Код следующий:

```
function MyArray() {    
    this.array = "";
    var separator = "#$#s";    
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        this.array += arguments[i] + separator;            
    }

    this.toString = function() {
        console.log(this.array);
    }
}
var a = new MyArray(1, 2, 3, "test");
console.log(a.toString());
```

Вопросы: почему в Firebug'e скрипт возвращает console.log(this.array) = пустой строке? В правильном ли направлении решается задача?

Comment: функция `this.toString` разве что-то возвращает? если нет, то поэтому и `a.toString()` ничего не возвращает.

Answer (score 2):

Всё правильно написано. Чтобы `this.array` не был пустым, нужно инициализировать `MyArray` какими-то параметрами.

Comment: this.array инициализируется при создании объекта в цикле for, вот и непонятно, почему он пустой при вызове метода toString()

Comment: Вы вызываете код в точности, как написали здесь ? Если так - то он рабочий.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в Firebug'e. При перезапуске Firefox'a и повторном запуске скрипта this.array не пустой.